# How to find if a class has any objects created based on it's definition?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to search the ruby environment for variables of a given class?

I have a class Connection. From any code in my application I want to be able to return any Connection that have been instantiated. Is that possible?

For example:

```
conns = ObjectSpace.find_objects_with_class(Connection)
```

I'm trying to find a globally defined database connection object that may or may not be there, if it's not there my code creates the connection.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement the singleton pattern. This does not seem like a good way to go about it.

Comment: I'm working with a gem that could probably benefit from connection pooling, https://github.com/klobuczek/active_node/issues/5

Comment: My original comment stands. Using some sort of hidden pool variable is preferable to hacking around ObjectSpace.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. I've never heard of a hidden variable. I'm not sure we can count on all applications defining the pool variable the same way, so I wanted to find the connection myself, sawa seems to have a better solution Connection.instance_variables should return the variables I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Connection).to_a
```

will give you the list of all `Connection` instances.

```
Connection.instance_variables
Connection.class_variables
```

will give you instance and class variables of `Connection` respectively.

Comment: Note: `ObjectSpace` contains all objects in the garbage collected memory. Including those that are no longer reachable but haven't been collected yet.